# How to interpret Scipy's negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, negative-binomial-distribution, scipy

In Python Scipy I obtain the follow result and am not sure how to interpret it

```py
>>> scipy.stats.nbinom(n=2, p=0.5).pmf(1)
0.25
```

As far as I understood the negative binomial distribution, I should obtain with my function the probability of $2$ successes after only $1$ trial of Bernoulli experiment. Should the probability not be $0$?

Comment: The `scipy` documentation has the pmf for the negative binomial distribution, and the expression there exactly matches the result you have here. Perhaps the function is parameterized in `scipy` differently than you expect?

Comment: @Sycorax ah yes, I see. The documentation states that the returned probability mass is for `failures`, where I assumed it would be the probability of `success`

Comment: This illustrates the value for users of packages to read the documentation, and for developers to ensure their documentation is readable to users.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation of scipy.stats.nbinom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html). The returned probability mass is the probability of `failure`, NOT `success`.